# Implicit differentiation of a lemniscate at a point:

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So here's the problem:

Find the slope of the tangent line of : 
$2(x^2 +y^2)^2 = 25(x^2 - y^2)$ at the point (3,1)

Cool: 
  So here's what I did:

Simplification step: 
$2(x^2 +y^2)^2 = 25(x^2 - y^2) \Rightarrow 2(x^2+y^2)^2 = 25x^2 - 25y^2$

Differentiate both sides:
$4(x^2 +y^2)(2x(x') + 2y(y')) = 50x(x') - 50y(y')$

Simplify:

$(4x^2 + 4y^2)(2x + 2y(y'))= 50x - 50y(y')$

$(4x^2 + 4y^2)(2x + 2y(y'))= 50x - 50y(y')$

$8x^3 + 8x^2y(y') + 8xy^2 + 8y^3(y')= 50x - 50y(y')$

$8x^2y(y') + 8y^3(y') + 50y(y') = 50x - 8x^3 + 8xy^2$

$(y') (8x^2y + 8y^3 + 50y) = 50x - 8x^3 + 8xy^2$

$y'  = \frac{50x - 8x^3 + 8xy^2}{8x^2y + 8y^3 + 50y}$

Cool, got y'...

Now, should I take the original equation and solve for y and substitute? I'm not even going to try putting down my steps on here.

The prompt is to find m=?

Someone please help?

Comment: Just plug in the given $x,y$. It is better not to simplify. Differentiate immediately. Also, I wouldn't bother solving for general $y'$. As soon as you have differentiated, substitute. Then solve.

Comment: as André suggests, you have $x=3$, you have $y=1$. So in your formula for $y'$ you can "Plug and chug"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start from 
$$2(x^2+y^2)^2=25(x^2-y^2).$$
Don't hesitate, Differentiate. We get
$$4(x^2+y^2)(2x+2yy')=50x-50yy'.$$
Substitute $x=3$, $y=1$. We get
$$4(10)(6+2m)=150-50m,$$
and therefore $130m=-90$.

Comment: the equation is actually $2(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 25(x^2 - y^2)$, but thank you!

Comment: I bombed on my simplification, didn't I?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, minor modification.

Comment: Bombing on simplification happens a lot, at least to me. That's a very good reason not to do it if you don't have to.

Comment: You are welcome. Often, "simplification" is uglification.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above were wrong since the equation is wrong. It should be the following -
y1= 8(x^2+y^2)-50)x/-(8(x^2+y^2)+50)y 
Then you get the slope as -9/13.

Comment: Can you provide a reason for why you say that the answers are wrong?